# Switch between two devices on one Thunderbolt Display

Tags: thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I'm using a Late 2011 Mac mini with High Sierra on a Thunderbolt Display, connected by a Thunderbolt cable to the Thunderbolt port on the back side of the display.

My wife has a Mid 2015 MacBook Pro, which she wants to use on the Thunderbolt Display when I'm at work. For the connection to the MacBook Pro I´m using the fixed power/Thunderbolt cable from the display.

I'm looking for a way to switch between the two devices when both are connected to the Thunderbolt Display.

Comment: Traditionally the way to share a single Keyboard Monitor and Video display is called a KVM. I searched for "Thunderbolt KVM" and found lots of results. Have you tried that?

Comment: hey,

thanks for your answers. this tread is not similar, because i´m running on TB1 on the mini and the display and TB2 on the MBP. This device you mentioned, is only for TB2 devices. and it is bloody expensive.

Comment: Anything Thunderbolt is expensive.  Thunderbolt 2 is backward compatible with TB 1, so technically the device works.  It's the answer, though it may not be what you want to hear.  Instead of looking for a TB KVM, I would 1) sell the TB monitor and 2) using the proceeds get a new monitor with multiple inputs instead.

Comment: if i could be sure upfront the setup works out of the box, i would buy it. but nobody can confirm it.

Comment: Usually products bought online carries a 30 day return (in the US at least).  Either way, I would still go with the monitor solution over the KVM - cheaper, more reliable, and better "life."  Thunderbolt Display is obsolete so regardless, your spending money on a dead product.